# How to pass some values throw ajax to VB.NET?

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net

Actually in my website i have a form and after a user submit it i use an iframe where i pass values to VB.NET codebehind throw QueryString, as i've read it's an "old" method for passing values to code behind so the question is how can i pass the values from the form throw AJAX to VB?

The data which the user will insert are name, surname, cellphone and other personal data, then these data's will be load in MySQL.

Here is button onClick method:

```
$("#addPrenotazione").click(function () {
    var orainizio =  $("#orainizio").val();
    var orafine =  $("#orafine").val()

    var timestart = orainizio.split(":");
    var inizio = timestart[0] * 4;
    var fullinizio = timestart[0] + ":" + timestart[1];

    var timeend = orafine.split(":");
    var fine = timeend[0] * 4;
    var fullfine = timeend[0] + ":" + timestart[1];

    var data = $("#data").val();
    var telefono = $("#telefono").val();
    var email = $("#email").val()

    var tavolo = $('#tavolo').val();
    var nome = $('#nome').val();
    var coperti = $('#coperti').val();
    var note = $('#descr').val();


    document.getElementById('post').src = "prenotazioni.aspx?NOME=" + nome + "&DATA=" + data + "&INIZIO=" + fullinizio + "&FINE=" + fullfine + "&TAVOLO=" + tavolo + "&COPERTI=" + coperti + "&NOTE=" + note + "&TELEFONO=" + telefono + "&EMAIL=" + email;

});
```

While here is the codebehind where i use the QueryString

```
  Sub WriteDB(ByVal nomeQS As String, ByVal dataQS As String, ByVal inizioQS As String, ByVal fineQS As String, ByVal tavoloQS As String, ByVal copertiQS As String, ByVal noteQS As String, ByVal telefonoQS As String, ByVal emailQS As String)
        Dim NOME As String = nomeQS
        Dim DATA As String = dataQS
        Dim INIZIO As String = dataQS + " " + inizioQS
        Dim FINE As String = dataQS + " " + fineQS
        Dim TAVOLO As String = tavoloQS
        Dim COPERTI As String = copertiQS
        Dim NOTE As String = noteQS
        Dim TELEFONO As String = telefonoQS
        Dim EMAIL As String = emailQS

        Dim SQL As String = "INSERT INTO prenota_tavoli (DATAIN_PTV, ORAIN_PTV, ORAOUT_PTV, NUMTAV_PTV, NUMCOP_PTV, EMACLI_PTV, TELCLI_PTV, NOTE_PTV, DESCLI_PTV) VALUES (@data, @orain, @oraout, @numtav, @numcop, @email, @tel, @note, @nome)"
        Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()

            With cmd
                .CommandText = SQL
                .Connection = con
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", DATA)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@orain", INIZIO)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@oraout", FINE)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numtav", TAVOLO)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@numcop", COPERTI)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", EMAIL)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", TELEFONO)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@note", NOTE)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", NOME)


            End With

            Try
                con.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            Finally
                con.Close()
            End Try
        End Using

    End Sub
```

Comment: This site is not a place where people teach you how to do things from scratch or write your code for you. You need to do the research yourself and then make an attempt. If you encounter a specific issue in doing that, then would be the time to post a question about that issue specifically.

Comment: Look into `XMLHttpRequest`, or one of the frameworks that wraps it, like `jQuery.ajax`

Comment: @jmcilhinney the problem is that i'm yet using AJAX to pass data from VB.NET and i've found lot of guides on how to pass the data from codebehind to ajax but not the opposite